# CCRendererSharedTypes file not found

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, metal

I am trying to upgrade Cocos2D in my project to 3.4 however I keep running into this same error. In the CCShaders.metal file it states that the CCRendererSharedTypes.h file is not found. It most certainly is in my project so I am not sure why it cannot find it.

I also made sure the header search paths included cocos2d/cocos2d-ui , etc. (the same way the example project does it)

I upgraded from 3.1 manually by replacing the files within Xcode as the Spritebuilder update method was not working for me and didn't update any of my files.

Is there any reason for this and how do I fix it?

Comment: probably just a header search path issue, create a new v3.4 project and apply the paths from the new project to yours

Comment: @LearnCocos2D that is exactly what I did to no avail however. Could it be anything else?

Comment: any progress on this issue?

Comment: SOLVED: used #import "cocos2d/CCRendererSharedTypes.h" and it worked. in my project this is the path relative to the project directory.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this step:

- Go to `Build Settings`
- Search for `Header Search Path` under `Metal
  Compiler - Build Options`
- Add the folder path of
  CCRendererSharedTypes.h file (cocos2d/cocos2d in my case)